# riemann integrable functions map to another one

Tags: analysis

I have the following question to prove:
If $f_{1}, f_{2},...,f_{n}$ are Riemann integrable functions, and $\phi$ a function from $R^{n}$ to $R$, where $R$ denotes the set of real numbers, such that $\phi$ is monotone with respect to each of its coordinates, prove that $\phi(f_1,...,f_n)$ is also Riemann integrable.

I had the following: approach $\phi(f_1,...,f_n)$ with $\phi(\psi_1,...,\psi_n)$ where $\psi_{i}$ is a  step function that controls $f_i$ however I have some trouble controlling the difference without any hypothesis regarding the linearity.
EDIT: I'm currently trying with $n = 1$ , aka $\phi$ is a monotone function. One thing that I know is that it has countable discontinuity points.
Could i get some hints? THanks in advance